# Single-file Adminer issue with function and CSS

Tags: php, mysql, adminer

I'm trying to use the single-file Adminer version ([this one](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/releases/download/v4.8.1/adminer-4.8.1-mysql-en.php) to be specific) from my codebase. That codebase is needed to perform some checks before accessing Adminer.

Composer autoloading in my application leads to the following issue when trying to use Adminer:
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare h() (previously declared in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/apps/vb/vendor/cakephp/core/functions.php:41`

I tried to rename `h()` in the adminer file to something like `h_adminer()`, but then the stylesheet seems to become corrupt (maybe charset related?).

Some of my classes need to be loaded, so I can't just get rid of the autoloader, or I'd need to manually load all classes & dependencies I need (not ideal).

Any suggestions to best deal with this issue are most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: So you are _not_ trying to use it stand-alone, but have it "embedded" into your cakephp application somehow?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I'm accessing the single-file version but need some additional checks from my application to be done before accessing it.

Comment: Add namespace to Adminer all classes and functions, then you will not have that issue

Comment: @Justinas Editing the file to include namespacing still gives the same issue with the CSS, so I think that's the main issue to resolve. `?file=default.css&amp;version=4.8.1` doesn't return readable CSS anymore.